# NGINX RTMP not working with sites-enabled directory set

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, rtmp

I'm having problems getting NGINX with the RTMP module to start when the RTMP server block is used within a file inside the `sites-available` (symbolic linked to `sites-enabled`). NGINX configuration files are all located at `/etc/nginx/`.

If I use the below RTMP server block directly in the `nginx.conf`, the server starts up perfectly fine. However, as soon I remove the comment from the line `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` in the `nginx.conf`,  `systemctl status nginx.service` comes back with`"nginx: [emerg] "rtmp" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/livestream:1`

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size;

        application obs_output {
            live on:
            record off;
        }
    }
}
```

These are the two guides I followed to install NGINX and the RTMP module.

- https://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/create-your-own-live-video-streaming-server-with-linux/
- https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/setup-rtmp-streaming-server/

Any ideas what's going on here please?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe you can declare an `rtmp {}` block from within the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory.

By default, the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory is included within an existing `http {}` block.  You can check this by looking at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.  You cannot have the `rtmp` block within the `http` block, they need to be separate from each other as they are declared at the same level.

The only `nginx` `include` that may fit your config would be from within the `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled` directory.